# How to get the beginning part of note content with evernote api on iOS

Tags: ios, evernote

I want to get the beginning part of note content, but the full version of note content. just like the text displayed on the subtitle field of a note cell in Evernote official app on iOS.

findNotes or findNotesMetadata function can't get note content, getNoteContent function will return the full version of note content.

which API should be used to get this information? or I have to through getNoteContent function for each note to get the beginning part of each note content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no public API today for grabbing just the beginning of the content.

Comment: Thanks, I will get it by getNoteContent